# Automatically add folder to PATH (Environment Variable) using Batch/Node.js

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, system, environment

I am trying to make a CLI program (basically a compiler like node) and I am making the installer, the problem is that I can not add the Folder to Path, I tried with:

```
set PATH="%PATH%;F:\n-compile"
```

Then I went to

`Control Panel` >> `Sytem and Security` >> `System` >> `Advanced system settings` >> `Environment Variables` >> `PATH` >> `Edit...` and I do not see `F:\n-compile` for the system, not the User's PATH. I am trying to make it do it automatically as an Installer would do with Bash, if somebody has a solution I could use to do it in Node.js would be really helpful too.

Comment: Well to start with, your command `set PATH="%PATH%;F:\n-compile"` is not correct, it should probably have been, `Set "Path=%Path%F:\n-compile;"`, so that the doublequotes weren't included. However, `Set` only defines or undefines variables locally, i.e. within the context of the `cmd.exe` session it is running under. To create a variable to persist outside of that `cmd.exe` session, take a look at the `setx` command. Open a Command Prompt, type `setx /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read the information presented.

Comment: @Compo So It should look like `SETX PATH "%PATH%;F:\n-compile"`?

Comment: `SETX PATH "%PATH%;F:\n-compile"` worked perfectly for me, Thank you!

Comment: I told you to read the information presented! Your `%Path%` variable value, should already terminate with `;` so you should use `%PATH%F:\n-compile;`. However, I will add that you should never use `setx` with `%Path%`. Unlike other variables, `%Path%` is an amalgamation of both the Systeme and User Environment variables named `Path`. My advice would be, you are not using the correct method as part of your installation, to do this; and my opinion is, you should never add something to the environment, unless you first inform the end user, and offer them the opportunity to refuse.

Comment: Yes, I will only use this for my installer, and I understand what potential damage it could make to my computer if not used properly. Thanks for your Help!

Comment: What you're doing is wrong! I've told you not to use it. You should never allow any code which does this onto anyone elses PC, _or even one of your own, with more than one user_.

Comment: All right. I will not.

Comment: As already pointed out, `set PATH="%PATH%;F:\n-compile"`, which should actually read `set "PATH=%PATH%;F:\n-compile"`, sets variable only in the *current* `cmd.exe` session. The `setx` command is intended to set variables in *future* sessions (actually it changes related Registry settings). However, the `PATH` variable is something special, because the value present in a `cmd.exe` session is actually a combination of system- and user-specific settings, which would terribly be messed around with when using `setx`, so it is best to **never** use `setx` with the `PATH` variable!

Comment: Lets say you've used `%SystemRoot%\System32\setx.exe Path "%Path%F:\n-compile;"`. What happens is that it takes the value content of your System `%Path%` and adds all of that to your User environment, together with the new location. Next time you open a cmd.exe instance and `Echo %Path%`, it will contain your new entry, but shows that you have many duplicates, _(those previously in the system environment)_. You have therefore technically corrupted that variable, hence my previous advice.